# Could not find PostScript font name (mPdf)

Tags: php, mpdf

I have a problem when generating PDF from an invoice (invoiceplane, server on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS), i’m getting this error:

```
Could not find PostScript font name: /xxxxx/invoiceplane/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Config/…/…/ttfonts/DejaVuSerifCondensed.ttf
```

I just updated mPdf (via composer) but nothing changes.
I’m on this for hours…

Has someone already had this ?

(initial question posted here: https://community.invoiceplane.com/t/topic/5273)

Comment: Have you gone into the directory `/xxxxx/invoiceplane/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Config/…/…/ttfonts/`  ??  Does it exist?

Comment: yes and it contains a lot of "DejaVu" fonts

Comment: so via command line you can literally `cd /var/www/mallo/invoiceplane/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Config/…/…/ttfonts/` ??  What are the dots in the directory?  Is that purposefully obfuscated?

Comment: no the dots came from the error message

Comment: That's where the issue lies .. I'd trace out where it's actually looking for the `font` --  I have a feeling where it's "looking" it's not "actually" where the font is installed.  So the directory doesn't exist.  Trace where it's "looking" for the font -- Find the problem.  In addition --  A good IDE like PHPStorm helps with finding declarations for you, so you're not sifting through code.  Simple as right-click->Go to_>Declaration

Comment: this is working fine: ``cd var/www/mallo.be/invoiceplane/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Config/../../ttfonts`` . I'm not debugging my own code, this is an existing application i installed on my server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159609/discussion-between-leto-and-zak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, which having no relation with mPdf, i'm using WinSCP to transfer files from local to my server and for an unknown reason, `transfer mode` was set to `binary` (i had also problem with images that were broken)